# Row locking in Maria database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a row in a Maria DB table that will be updated (incremented) many times by different users at the same exact time, and I don't want to miss any update. Is "row locking" enabled by default for all Maria/Mysql databases, or a configuration is needed?

Comment: There's very little chance that they will all be done at **precisely** the same time.

Comment: If you want to get notified of every update, you might want to look into triggers for tables.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly.  Period.  No configuration needed; none available in InnoDB.

What is this, a `Like` counter or `Views` counter?  I recommend moving such out of the main table.  This is because the rapid-fire updates will make it difficult to get to the main columns.  And vice versa.  (Please provide more details to discuss further.)